# TableView error delegate, proxy changed from the time it was first set

Tags: swift, uitableview, observable, rx-swift

I get this error:

> assert(proxy === DelegateProxy.currentDelegate(for: object), "Proxy
>   changed from the time it was first set.
>
> Original: (proxy)
>
> Existing:
>   (String(describing: DelegateProxy.currentDelegate(for: object)))")

I have two observables that handles to xib storyboard on different states but once one of them has been loaded I receive the error above, I have tried to use the `self.tableView.delegate = nil & self.tableView.dataSource = nil` but yet it causes this on the `.bind(to:)` function. My problem is I don't know how to handle it before this error:

> Assertion failed: Proxy changed from the time it was first set.

Original:

```
.asObservable().bind(to:(tableView?.rx.items(cellIdentifier: 
      aTableViewCell.Identifier, cellType: HaTableViewCell.self))!


func initTableView() {

    // pull to refresh
    aViewModel
        .isLoading
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe({ (loading) in
            if loading.element == false { 
            } else {
                self.tableView!.delegate = self // loads a shimmering view
                self.tableView!.dataSource = self
            }
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    aViewModel
        .datas
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to:(tableView?.rx.items(cellIdentifier: aTableViewCell.Identifier, cellType: HaTableViewCell.self))!) { (index, element, cell) in
         // when the data is fired load this tableview cell
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

How can set the the tableview to nil before the data Observables fires up?

> This is a feature to warn you that there is already a delegate (or data 
>   source) set somewhere previously. The action you are trying to perform ? 
>   will clear that delegate (data source) and that means that some of your ?features that depend on that delegate (data source) being set will likely stop working. If you are ok with this, try to set delegate (data source) to `nil` in front of this operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

In general, you should *not* set 'tableView.dataSource' or 'tableView.delegate' when using RxDataSources with it.

If you want to bind different observables as datasource to the same tableView, '.switchLatest()' operator is what you need.

Comment: I am trying to have a shimmering view during the loading of the data, once the data is there show the data in the table view. I am using FBShimmer library. I have set the shimmering view without using RxSwift but the RxSwift is only used when I have the data observables data.

Comment: @RHJ I see no problem there. You have full control of your cells via 'dataSource.configureCell' and 'tableView.rx.willDisplayCell' methods. Provide your shimmering view via one of the above methods.

Comment: I am not using RxDataSources, is that what you recommend me to use for shimmering table view cell during loading of data? The shimmering view has no observables will that be okay? I have only used RxSwift, RxCocoa.

Comment: @RHJ Ah, I did not realise you were not using it. Indeed, I would definitely recommend RxDataSources, it is one of the most useful Rx frameworks out there. See examples on its page - https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources

Comment: And how will I solve the shimmering with this library? The shimmering view is basically just empty views and I’ve no data inside?

Comment: @RHJ I do not understand how exactly you are using shimmering views. Is it for cells? If so, you can make an Observable of enum type (loading state and actual data), and dequeue either a shimmering or a regular cell in 'dataSource.configureCell'.

Comment: Referencing instance method 'switchLatest()' on 'SharedSequenceConvertibleType' requires that '[MyModel]' conform to 'SharedSequenceConvertibleType' So, how to use switchLatest?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you associate to a delegate via RxCocoa, you need to make sure you clean that disposable in order to reuse with a different one.

In swift you don't need to set to nil, pointing to other memory slot will do the work.

```
func refreshTableView() {

disposable = DisposeBag()
// pull to refresh
aViewModel
    .datas
    .asObservable()
    .bind(to:(tableView?.rx.items(cellIdentifier: aTableViewCell.Identifier, cellType: HaTableViewCell.self))!) { (index, element, cell) in
     // when the data is fired load this tableview cell
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```